# Describing a relationship that is related via a third party?

Tags: phrase-requests

How do you describe something where

**A does not cause B**,

but

**C causes A and B**.

What would you call the relationship between C and A/B and the relationship between A and B? I'm sure there's some logical terminology for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that since c causes a and b, there might be a confusion among the observers that 'a' has some role to play in causing 'b'?

Comment: @JonyAgarwal yes exactly.

Comment: You should try this question in MathOverflow or Theoretical Computer Science SE sites!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phsycology we call variables that correlate **covariants**, thus saying they vary together but not necessarily cause each other.

From [M-W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-cause_fallacy):

> Covariant: varying with something else so as to preserve certain mathematical interrelations

This doesn't necessarily mean there's a common cause to both of them (c is causing both a and b), but it conveys the idea that, even though a and b are related, they aren't necessarily a cause for one another.

Also see [Third-cause fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-cause_fallacy)

Another word is **confounded**, although this one is pretty much restricted to Statistics and may have negative connotations. From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding):

> "We say that X and Y are confounded by some other variable Z whenever Z is a cause of both X and Y."

Answer (score 4):

We could call the relation between A and B to be **coincidental/correlated** and the one between C and A/B to be **causal relationship**. I would suggest you to look into [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation#The_relationship_between_A_and_B_is_coincidental) to not just get some more insight into the subject matter but also the relationship label.