# Is there a word or phrase for a third-party contractor of a third-party entity?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, business-language

Consider the following:

- I represent **Company A**
- **Company A** has a contractor that they offload work to, called **Company B**
- **Company B** has a contractor that they offload **Company A**'s work to, called **Company C**
- Each of these companies renders services, not physical goods. In a sense, they all operate in a single supply chain, but it doesn't fit the overall context of the relationship well.

Because of this, I would call **Company B** a third-party entity to **Company A**. I would also call **Company C** a third-party entity to **Company B**.

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/296289/describing-a-relationship-that-is-related-via-a-third-party) is close, but it doesn't quite capture the hierarchy or context of this.

With this in mind, what are some appropriate options to describe the relationship **Company C** has to **Company A**? Essentially, how do I state a relationship about a third party's third party?

Comment: Sounds like just another third party, a subcontractor, or an indirect contractor.

Comment: Subcontractor does fit well in the context. It captures the hierarchy of the relationship.

Comment: **Subcontractor** is the formal term in the UK construction industry. Company C has no formal relationship to Company A, but Company A might stipulate which other companies that Company B may subcontract to.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree. Company A is the client, Company B is the main contractor and Company C is the subcontractor. Of course if A is contracted to Company X then X is the client, A is the main contractor, B is the subcontractor  and C is the sub-subcontractor but that starts to get really complex.